# Creating a view in schema1 from a table in schema2 throws "permission to the schema2 denied

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am trying to create a view in one schema in aws redshift, by pulling the data from another schema.

Here is the query used

```
create or replace view user_1 as
select * from schema2.table_name a
where a.field_name= 'IN'
```

This throws an error ' permission denied for schema2 ' Both the schemas are in the same data base . Could anyone help me to understand what is wrong with this.

Comment: The schema2 owner hasn't granted select on the table?

Comment: Can you run `select * from schema2.table_name`?

Comment: Yes, The schema2 Owner had not granted permission to select. Thats why it didnt work.